# Why won't my JS html display in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I'm trying so hard to fix my code but i don't know whats wrong. the html file is in the same folder as the libraries, but it won't show up in my firefox or chrome whatsoever. i even tried a different pc.

### whats wrong with it ?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src=dateLibrary.js></script>
<script src=drawingLibrary.js></script>
<script language=javascript>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function drawLine(14, 'blue' , 0);

var dateOfBirth = new Date(1989,2,18);
var dateInShort = dateStringShort(dateOfBirth);
document.write("birthday in short form is:" + dateInLong);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well you have a script tag that is not closed and script inside of a body tag, not a script...

Comment: i fixed it but its still not showing up

Comment: I believe it should be src="drawingLibrary.js", with the quotations mark

Answer (score 0):

Your opening `script` tag doesn't have a closing tag and it's in the wrong place.

Also, you don't call a function using the word `function`, you just say the name of the function and pass any arguments in parenthesis.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src=dateLibrary.js></script>
    <script src=drawingLibrary.js></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script>
      drawLine(14, 'blue' , 0);

      var dateOfBirth = new Date(1989,2,18);
      var dateInShort = dateStringShort(dateOfBirth);
      document.write("birthday in short form is:" + dateInLong);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you i fixed it but its still not showing up :(

Comment: `function drawLine(14, 'blue' , 0);` is not valid

Comment: You need to make sure that you have the files `dateLibrary.js` and `drawingLibrary.js` in the same folder as this HTML file and you need to make sure that there is a function in one of those files called `drawLine` that expects a number, a string (for a color) and another number as arguments.

Comment: i removed it, its still not showing up. i honestly still don't know whats wrong. i think something's wrong inside the <head> because i removed the whole head part and just wrote
document.write("hello"); inside the body and it worked.

Comment: the libraries are in the same folder as the HTML and the functions are in there too.

Comment: @skully The line should not be `function drawLine(14, 'blue' , 0);`, it should be: `drawLine(14, 'blue' , 0);`. But again, if the libraries are not in the right place and the function doesn't exist or you aren't passing the correct values to it, it won't work.

Comment: @ScottMarcus i did take the word function out. and the libraries are in the right place. they are in the same folder as the html file. it still won't display. i'm really confused. i made sure everything is right. i think something's wrong in the <head> part.

Comment: @skully Again, the problem is NOT in the `head`. The problem is the way you are calling the function that is declared within one of those libraries. If you press F12 while the page is open and click on the Console tab of the developer tools window, you will see an error message. It will give a message and it will give a line number and even the file that the error is occurring in. Please post that EXACT information.

Comment: The references to the .js files need to be put in quotes also. <script src=dateLibrary.js> ---> <script src='dateLibrary.js'>

Comment: @chairmanmow No, they don't. Not unless there is a space in the path.  https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values

Comment: @ScottMarcus thanks for the clarification/link, my bad!